# Why postfix configuration recommends placing check_policy_service always after reject_unauth_destination?

Tags: postfix

Postfix manual recommends this :

> Be sure to specify check_sender_access and check_policy_service AFTER
> reject_unauth_destination or else your system could become an open
> mail relay.

I've **created my own policy_service** that only answers requests by DUNNO or DEFER_IF_PERMIT. Only these two. Default action is DUNNO

My smtpd_recipient_restrictions end like

```
 ..., check_policy_service { inet:127.0.0.1:19706, default_action=DUNNO },
 permit_mynetworks,
 permit_sasl_authenticated,
 reject_unauth_destination
```

My understanding is that if my policy_service somehow responds with ACCEPT or the like, all following checks, including reject_unauth_destination are skipped and mail is accepted, thus allowing my server to relay mail to random address from random source. But DUNNO and DEFER* always ensure following checks are made.

Am I over-confident about my thought?

(I had to put check_policy_service before permit_sasl_authenticated because my policy_service must scan inbound as well as outgoing mail. I don't really recall why I've had to put reject_unauth_destination after permit_sasl_authenticated).

Comment: Actually yes I think. Port 25 is generally blocked by ISP in my region. Customers were given (by me, my bad) port `465` *or* `587` for MUA configuration. So I think both ports accept outgoing mails and `permit_sasl_authenticated` is needed for both.

Comment: That sounds perfectly fine: That sounds like you *do* have a clear separation between port 25 (inbound only, not used by MUAs) and port 465/587 (accepts outgoing mail, because it only talks to authenticated MUAs). If I understood that right, depending on what exactly your policy service does, it might make sense to have distinct restriction sets for 25 and for 465&587.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes,** this is the main reason for recommending such order - if only restriction classes less commonly risking an open relay precede the eventual `reject_unauth_destination` or `reject` statement, then it is less likely that a mistake in ordering those rules leads to an ACCEPT that skips later checks which would and should have resulted in REJECT.

Additionally, it often simply a waste of resources to consult an (comparatively expensive) external filter on mails that would then get rejected for more obvious reasons anyway (e.g. you would usually run a spam filter *after* skipping over mails that you will definitely not be relaying anyway).

**Yes,** after explicitly configuring a non-accepting default_action and ensuring your filter never accepts mail, ordering a policy service before `reject_unauth_destination` can be a safe configuration. Be careful about additional places that could result in an ACCEPT result, such as the behaviour for edge cases or exception of any libraries you used to implement your policy service.

**However,** depending on what your policy service does (does it only police your authenticated users? does it only enforce restrictions on unauthenticated mail?) you might be able to keep adhering to the recommendation with one of the following approaches:

- Split your restrictions: Apply a completely distinct set of restrictions on unauthenticated internet mail (received via port 25) and on authenticated submissions fro MUAs (received via port 465, possibly also 587)
- Make use of the other restriction classes (recipient, sender, relay, client, ..). E.g. your policy service only looks at information already available at connection request stage, it might be more appropriate to call it from the `smtpd_client_restrictions` and never have `check_policy_service` and `reject_unauth_destination` in the same restriction class i the first place, so that their order has different (though, still not necessarily harmless) consequences